# How to use VBA to connect SQL server and export SQL result

Tags: sql-server, vba

I have used  below code but failed at step

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Can anyone help to check why?

```vb
Sub get_Data_From_DB()

   Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
   Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

   ' Open a connection by referencing the ODBC driver.

    cnn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};" & _
       "server=aaaaa,2431;uid=bbb;pwd=ccc;database=ddd"
    cnn.Open

   ' Find out if the attempt to connect worked.
   If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then
      MsgBox "Welcome to Pubs!"
      Sql = "SELECT top 10 * from tableA(NOLOCK)"

      Set rs = cnn.Execute(Sql)

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.CopyFromRecordset rs
   Else
      MsgBox "Sorry. No Pubs today."
   End If


   ' Close the connection.
   cnn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.CopyFromRecordset rs
```

To something like this:

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

You can change "A1" to another cell if you'd like.

EDIT: Here's how I'd actually organize this to make it flexible/reusable.

```vb
Sub runPubsQuery

    Dim sqlStr As String
    sqlStr = "SELECT top 10 * FROM tableA(NOLOCK)"

    Call writeSqlResults(sqlStr,getConnectionString(),ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"))

End Sub
Sub writeSQLResults(sqlStr As String, connStr As String, destWS As Worksheet, _
                    Optional errMsg As String = "Sorry. No Pubs today.", Optional welcMsg As String = "Welcome to Pubs!")

    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim headerArr As Variant

    cn.Open (connStr)

    If Not cn.State = adStateOpen Then
        MsgBox errMsg
    Else
        MsgBox welcMsg
        Set rs = cn.Execute(sqlStr)

        If Not rs.EOF Then
            headerArr = getRecordHeaders(rs)
            With destWS
                .Cells.Clear
                .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, UBound(headerArr, 2))).Value = headerArr
                .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
            End With
            rs.Close
        End If
    End If

    cn.Close

End Sub
Function getConnectionString(Optional serverName As String = "aaaa,2431", Optional dbName As String = "ddd", _
                             Optional uidStr As String = "bbb", Optional pwdStr As String = "ccc") As String

    getConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};" & _
                          "Server=" & serverName & ";" & _
                          "Uid=" & uidStr & ";" & _
                          "Pwd=" & pwdStr & ";" & _
                          "Database=" & dbName & ";"

End Function
Function getRecordHeaders(rs As Variant) As Variant

    If Not TypeName(rs) = "Recordset" Then
        MsgBox "Error: Parameter rs is not a valid recordset"
        Stop
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ReDim headerArr(1 To 1, 1 To rs.Fields.Count) As Variant
        j = 0
        For i = LBound(headerArr, 2) To UBound(headerArr, 2)
            headerArr(1, i) = rs.Fields(j).Name
            j = j + 1
        Next
        getRecordHeaders = headerArr
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: Recordset is empty"
        Stop
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: thank you! Works but how can I get column names too ?

Comment: Technically, that is not your question but iterate through [rs.Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38797891/1422451). Dump results in `A2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, to get all field naems and all records as well.

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()
     ' Carl SQL Server Connection
     '
     ' FOR THIS CODE TO WORK
     ' In VBE you need to go Tools References and check Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.x library
     '

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = "Your_Server_NameS" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "Your_DB_Name" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM [Customers]" ' Enter your SQL here

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
     ' Dump to spreadsheet
    For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2:z500") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
        '.ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '            Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```